# Filter git log by only merge-base and merge commits

Tags: bash, git

My git repository has multiple branches. I'd like to see a branch graph which describe how these branches divided and merged.

Consider this graph:

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline
*   eac03d9 (develop) Merge branch 'release/xxx' into develop
|\
* \   d94a368 Merge branch 'feature/xxx' into develop
|\ \
| * | 624b398 feat: xxx
| * | 9a87641 feat: xxx
| | | *   6bfbc30 (master) Merge branch 'release/xxx'
| | | |\
| | | |/
| | |/|
| | * | 8d85380 (release/xxx) fix: xxx
| | * | f7e9ef9 fix: xxx
| |/ /
|/| |
* | | 733751e feat: xxx
* | | d5efb9e feat: xxx
|/ /
* | 5ceb217 feat: xxx
* | ea70adf feat: xxx
* | eeff2a3 feat: xxx
|/
* b4b3db0 root
```

It contains many `feat: xxx` and `fix: xxx` commits, which i'd like to hidden. I'm looking for some `git log` options to filter only merge-base and merge commits.

For example:

```
*   eac03d9 (develop) Merge branch 'release/xxx' into develop
|\
* \   d94a368 Merge branch 'feature/xxx' into develop
|\ \
| | | *   6bfbc30 (master) Merge branch 'release/xxx'
| | | |\
| | | |/
| | |/|
| | * | 8d85380 (release/xxx) fix: xxx
| |/ /
|/| |
|/ /
|/
* b4b3db0 root
```

Comment: Your actual need is not clear. Can you explain ? `i'd like to hidden` - what you want to hide ?

Comment: Shouldn't this line be omitted in your expected output then `8d85380 (release/xxx) fix: xxx`?

Comment: This is not what you asked for, but consider `--simplify-by-decoration`.

Comment: @smilyface i want to hide the commits matched these conditions: a. it should have only one parent; b. it should have only one child.

Comment: @Inian It shouldn't omitted. Because i want to know which commit is these branches divided (children's num >= 2).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work for you.
`git log |  grep -vE "[a-zA-Z0-9] feat: xxx|[a-zA-Z0-9] fix: xxx"`

**Explanation :** 

1)
`|` -> Pipe will provide output of command at the LHS to RHS
Example : `git log | grep "fix"` will provide output of git log to `grep` command

2)
grep -vE -> v for avoiding / excluding , and E for adding more arguments within single grep (or I can say it as `or`, that is  `grep "a|b"` means show output if there is `a` or `b`

3)
[a-zA-Z0-9] -> is a regex to avoid special character (see here : https://regex101.com/r/DXmsTi/1)

**Update:**

```
git log |  grep -E " Merge branch |\(release/"
```

Comment: I guess this will not work perfectly cause:
a. Not all commit messages start with `feat` or `fix`. And I can't enumerate them.
b. If `8d85380` isn't referenced by branch `release`, it will be hidden too.

Comment: It works fine as of your question!! [ I got your point. But always make sure people wont get confuse / misunderstand the scenario ]. You only mentioned that too inside `code block` (It contains many feat: xxx and fix: xxx commits)

Comment: My mistake. The example of question isn't detailed enough.

Comment: In that case, you can just grep the word merge and release. I have updated my answer. Please check @LittleAngel